# Two different outputs from the same array

Tags: java, arrays, multithreading

The problem is as follows, I have a LocalDateTime array

```
        LocalDateTime[] alarmzeiten = new LocalDateTime[100];
```

and when the program starts, the array gets filled from a .dat when the program starts OR via userinput anytime in the program so the array brackets are either null or hold a LocalDateTime.

Besides the main function I have this thread:

```
    public void run() {
     while(true){
        for(int i = 0; i < alarmzeiten.length; i++){ 
            System.out.println(alarmzeiten[i]);
    }
```

The thread should constantly show me if something changes in the LocalDateTime array. If I safe the changes in the .dat and start the program again, it is no problem to see the changes made. The problem with this thread is though, that if I change the array somewhen in the program it still prints the array like in the beginning of the program. When the user makes changes in the array at any given point and I display the array with a button in the main function, it shows the array changed, like it´s supposed to be.

The part where the Array changes:

```
    JButton btnsetAlarm = new JButton("Alarm stellen");                                                         
    btnsetAlarm.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {                
        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) { 
            try{
            DateChooserToPieces datumsverarbeiter = new DateChooserToPieces(String.valueOf(dateChooser.getDate()));
            alarmzeiten[listAufgaben.getSelectedIndex()] = LocalDateTime.of(datumsverarbeiter.getYear(), datumsverarbeiter.getMonth(),
            datumsverarbeiter.getDay(), Integer.parseInt(String.valueOf(cbStunde.getSelectedItem())), Integer.parseInt(String.valueOf(cbMinute.getSelectedItem())));
            }
            catch(ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException ex){
                JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Bitte wählen Sie eine Aufgabe aus!");
            }
     }
```

I put the same problem in smaller code so I can post it all here for complete infromation! Here is the main part:

```
    import java.awt.BorderLayout;
    import java.awt.EventQueue;

    import javax.swing.JFrame;
    import javax.swing.JPanel;
    import javax.swing.border.EmptyBorder;
    import javax.swing.JTextField;
    import javax.swing.JButton;
    import java.awt.event.ActionListener;
    import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;

    public class VisualThreadTest extends JFrame {

private JPanel contentPane;
private JTextField textField;
String threadTestString = "Test";



/**
 * Launch the application.
 */
public static void main(String[] args) {
    EventQueue.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
        public void run() {

            try {
                VisualThreadTest frame = new VisualThreadTest();
                frame.setLocationRelativeTo(null);
                frame.setVisible(true);

            } catch (Exception e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
    });
}

/**
 * Create the frame.
 */
public VisualThreadTest() {
    setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
    setBounds(100, 100, 450, 300);
    contentPane = new JPanel();
    contentPane.setBorder(new EmptyBorder(5, 5, 5, 5));
    setContentPane(contentPane);
    contentPane.setLayout(null);


    Thread a = new Thread(new Thread1(threadTestString));
    a.start();

    JTextField tf = new JTextField();
    tf.setBounds(10, 11, 86, 20);
    contentPane.add(tf);
    tf.setColumns(10);

    JButton btnNewButton = new JButton("New button");       //here it should change threadTestString to something I put in the textfield and the Thread
    btnNewButton.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {   // should print the change
        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent arg0) {
            threadTestString=tf.getText();
            System.out.println(threadTestString);
        }
    });
    btnNewButton.setBounds(106, 10, 89, 23);
    contentPane.add(btnNewButton);

}
```

}

Here is the Class Thread1:

```
    public class Thread1 implements Runnable{
String threadString;
Thread1(String d){
    threadString = d;
}
    @Override public void run(){
        while(true){
            System.out.println(threadString + " Thread1");
            try {
                Thread.sleep(1000);
            } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
    }
```

}

Comment: Could you provide the part of the code where you change the array

Comment: Did you try to use AtomicReferenceArray instead of a simple array?

Comment: I just edited, so the part of the code where I change the array is here.

No so far I did not use AtomicReferenceArray.

Comment: @ManuelNeuer I suggest you to try using AtomicReferenceArray. The entries of alarmzeiten array are update from different threads afterall

Comment: @ManuelNeuer can you show us the code which is used when time array is not updated?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
    LocalDateTime[] alarmzeiten = new LocalDateTime[100];
```

is an array and element of an array are not consistently and reliably updated between thread sharing it.

According to your saying, the user actions are executed in another thread that which one that reads the array :

```
public void run() {
  while(true){
    for(int i = 0; i < alarmzeiten.length; i++){ 
        System.out.println(alarmzeiten[i]);
     }
}
```

Finally your problem is that the thread that prints the elements has a not updated version of the array object.

**How to solve it ?**

Using the volatile modifier will not be helpful as an array or a List with the `volatile` modifier does not provide the `volatile` behavior to its elements.

**A more reliable solution is using explicit synchronization when the array is used**.
You could use synchronized statements on the array when you access the array.
In this way, each thread will have an exclusive access to the array state and it will create a happens-before relationships that will provide the visibility of the object in its last version.

The thread that prints the elements could do :

```
public void run() {
 while(true){
    synchronized(alarmzeiten){
        for(int i = 0; i < alarmzeiten.length; i++){ 
            System.out.println(alarmzeiten[i]);
         }
    }
}
```

And in the thread user could do it :

```
synchronized(alarmzeiten){
     alarmzeiten[listAufgaben.getSelectedIndex()] = LocalDateTime.of(datumsverarbeiter.getYear(), datumsverarbeiter.getMonth(),
}
```

Comment: I tried it like that, unfortunately it didn´t work. Can I provide you with some more information?

Comment: Sure. Could you show the class where alarmzeiten is declared ?

Answer (score 0):

I would make a Java solution that uses a *monitor* for unique data access to `alarmzeiten`, in a thread-safe manner. I provide a code-snippet here:

```
    public class timePrint implements Runnable {
       private LocalDateTime[] alarmzeiten = new LocalDateTime[100];

       public LocalDateTime[] getAlarmzeiten() {
           synchronized (alarmzeiten) {
               return alarmzeiten;
           }
       }

       public void setAlarmzeiten(LocalDateTime[] alarmzeiten) {
           synchronized (alarmzeiten) {
               this.alarmzeiten = alarmzeiten;
           }
       }

       @Override
       public void run() {
           while (true) {
               synchronized (alarmzeiten) {
                   for (LocalDateTime localDateTime : alarmzeiten) {
                       System.out.println(localDateTime);
                   }
               }
               try {
                   Thread.sleep(1000);
               } catch (Exception e) {
                   System.out.println(e);
               }
           }
       }
   }
```

(Code-snippet modified as to incorporate shared memory within `Runnable`).
Note that the other access points to `alarmzeiten` need also to use a `synchronized` construct (for thread-safe shared memory access).
The `sleep` is needed to release the thread-access of your shared data array.

You can add a separate get method with an array index as input argument. Also a similar set method (using an index) can be implemented. Both methods need using a `synchronized` construct.

Comment: Thank you for your answer, I also tried this, unfortunately this didn´t work either

Answer (score 0):

Multi threaded environment also you need to consider visibility i.e some synchronization or compareAndSet which is like non blocking mechanism for memory synchronization.

You can use `CopyOnWriteArrayList ob= new CopyOnWriteArrayList();`collection.
here while iteration no locking is required and also no concurrentmodification exception.

```
public class CopyOnWriteArrayListExample {

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        List<Integer> list = new CopyOnWriteArrayList<>();

        list.add(1);
        list.add(2);
        list.add(3);
        list.add(4);
        list.add(5);

        new WriteThread("Writer", list).start();

        new ReadThread("Reader", list).start();

    }
}


class WriteThread extends Thread {

    private List<Integer> list;

    public WriteThread(String name, List<Integer> list) {
        this.list = list;
        super.setName(name);
    }

    public void run() {
        int count = 6;

        while (true) {

            try {

                Thread.sleep(5000);

            } catch (InterruptedException ex) {
                ex.printStackTrace();
            }

            list.add(count++);

            System.out.println(super.getName() + " done");
        }
    }
}


class ReadThread extends Thread {
    private List<Integer> list;

    public ReadThread(String name, List<Integer> list) {
        this.list = list;
        super.setName(name);
    }

    public void run() {

        while (true) {

            String output = "\n" + super.getName() + ":";

            Iterator<Integer> iterator = list.iterator();

            while (iterator.hasNext()) {
                Integer next = iterator.next();
                output += " " + next;

                // fake processing time
                try {

                    Thread.sleep(10);

                } catch (InterruptedException ex) {
                    ex.printStackTrace();
                }
            }

            System.out.println(output);
        }
    }
}
```

or you can check concurrent package.Also you can use atomicreferencearray.

```
AtomicReferenceArray<String> array = 
    new AtomicReferenceArray<String>(source);


array.compareAndSet(5, string1, string2);
```